# Keep good url after RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 2 goals :

-> ask to google that it's permanent redirection

-> keep original url when redirection is done

with this code, redirection url is */index.php?com=location&lID=$1* not *location/([0-9]+)*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  location/([0-9]+).* /index.php?com=location&lID=$1 [R=301,L]
```

but when i delete R=301 flag (i just keep L flag) redirection url is ok but i don't think google will appreciate

Comment: Not only Google. It seems clear that you don't want a permanent redirection to a CODE variable. The page is the same, there are only modifications to the query string.

Comment: I have an existing url (built as /index.php?com=location&lID=$1), i want to change to improve SEO